# Верны ли знаки препинания? Прошу помощи

Tags: пунктуация

**Стоимость кислородного концентратора, который вырабатывает 3 литра кислорода в минуту, – от 50 тысяч рублей. Чаще покупают пятилитровые, а для больных с низкой сатурацией необходимы аппараты, рассчитанные на 10 литров – и ценовой сегмент здесь уже другой – от 70 и 105 тысяч соответственно.**

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт уместности «людей»... Не больные, не пациенты они в этом контексте?

Первое тире заменил бы на *составляет*: от 50 и выше. Окончание второй фразы дал бы в такой редакции: *рассчитанные на 10 литров (ценовой сегмент здесь уже другой), стоимостью от 70 и 105 тысяч рублей соответственно*.

Comment: Да, больные. Спасибо за замечание

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. Ваш вариант правки более уместен. Обилие тире мне не нравится.